# keras data generator to tensorflow input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a deep learning model in a distributive way. I have built my model in Keras and now I need to transform my model to a tensorflow estimator in order for it to work. Since my dataset is already big enough and it will grow bigger as I collect more data, I used `ImageDataGenerator` followed by `flow_from_directory`. I specify that I want batches of size 32 with desired shape, which is (299, 299, 3). Therefore, the output are batches of (32, 299, 299, 3). Before, I just feed the objects to `model.fit_generator` and Keras takes care of the rest.

So far, I have converted my Keras model to a tensorflow estimator, but I can't figure out if I can use the object from the `flow_from_directory` to train the data using tf.train. I have already tried to write my own `input_fn` but I got confused. Your help is highly appreciated.